# How do I set a minimum length for an integer in an XML Schema?

Tags: xml, xsd

I am in the process of creating an XML Schema and one of my values is a year.  As such, I'd like to ensure that all values have exactly 4 characters.  To do so, I am using the following syntax:

```
<xs:element name="publish_year" maxOccurs="1">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:positiveInteger">
      <xs:totalDigits value="4"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>                                      
</xs:element>
```

If I'm understanding "totalDigits" correctly, someone could pass in a "publish_year" value of "2008" or "200".  Both would be valid.  As such, how can I structure my XSD to ensure 4 digits are required?  At first blush, I'm guessing I'd use a regex, but I'd like to know if I'm overlooking something that's already baked in (like "totalDigits")

UPDATE:

I went with the following solution. It may be overkill, but it gets the point across:

```
<xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:positiveInteger">
        <xs:totalDigits value="4" fixed="true"/>
        <xs:minInclusive value="1900"/>
        <xs:pattern value="^([1][9]\d\d|[2]\d\d\d)$"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want left zero-padding, i.e. 0000, 0001 to 9999?

Comment: If no padding is requiered, I just added the 'fixed' attribute suggestion

Comment: Can we really assign regex using xml schema ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about a plage of value as an additional restriction ?

([minInclusive](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#rf-minInclusive) - [maxInclusive](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dc-maxInclusive))

For instance ?

```
<xs:minInclusive value="1900"/> et <xs:maxInclusive value="2008"/>
```

But to get back to the [totalDigits](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dt-totalDigits) constraint, why do you not set the `fixed` attribute to true ?

> If {fixed} is true, then types for which the current type is the {base type definition} cannot specify a value for totalDigits other than {value}.

```
<xs:totalDigits value="4" fixed="true" />
```

Comment: Why doesn't it answer the question?

Comment: The first comment was written at the time when I did not yet added the 'fixed' suggestion on the totalDigits element ;-)

Comment: Ancient question...but either I am misunderstanding or "fixed" does not quite mean what you think. My interpretation is It doesn't fix it to exactly 4 digits but ensures that any type based on that type can't specify anything other than 4.

Comment: @Ian1971 that is possible (6+ years later, I am a bit fuzzy on the topic). Do you have a link to a documentation which could help?

Comment: Actually you have everything in your answer already, including the quote and the link. I just think it was misinterpreted.  I noticed because I was using fixed to try and do what is sounds like it does i.e. fix the number of digits, but my schema was being validated as ok with that number of digits or less.

Comment: @Ian1971 ok, what edit would you propose in order for the answer to *not* misinterpret "fixed"?

Comment: I think the minInclusive/maxInclusive alone or pattern constraint solves this particular issue, even though it would be nicer to be able to say "exactly 4 digits" via the totalDigits constraint.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the base type xs:gYear, with additional constraining facets, as needed. For more info, [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#built-in-datatypes) might help.